# Docker: Windows does not support host IP addresses in NAT settings

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Launching a Docker container with docker-compose fails with:

```sh
$ docker-compose up
Cannot start service NAME: failed to create endpoints NAME on network my_net: Windows does not support host IP addresses in NAT settings.
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

This is on Windows 10, using Docker 2.1.0.1, Docker-compose 1.24.1.

The `docker-compose.yml` section with network looks simply like this (empty):

```
networks:
  my_net:
```

What does this `Windows does not support host IP addresses in NAT settings` error mean? How do I fix it?

Note that the same steps with the same YAML config work fine on other machines (Linux). I'm not familiar with Windows Docker – does it need some special settings, somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: For those that are viewing this issue later on, please ensure you're on the latest version of Docker Desktop:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/10552